# VueJS + Firebase timing problem at startup

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack, firebase-authentication

I have a VueJS (ts) app with Firebase authentication. I largely followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtbYBoKb2zY).

Despite creating the app **only after** the initialization of Firebase (see code below), I get an error that Firebase is apparently not initialized:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

My code looks like this:

```js
// main.ts
...
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let app: Vue;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!app) {        // create app only after firebase has been initialized
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
}
)
```

```js
// App.vue
<script>
...

import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

function logUser() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => 
      console.log("user = " + user)
  )
}

logUser();   // throws the exception
window.setTimeout( () => logUser(), 1000)   // works!!

...

</script>
```

I build my app  with `npm run build` and serve it with `firebase serve`.

I suspect that webpack might somehow try to optimize things and create the Vue instance (or, more precisely, the elements of the router) before the actual Firebase authentication callback happens.

**Q** How could firebase still be not initialized? How can I get rid of this random timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that it is a problem with the `import` statement - the code in `App.vue` is actually executed at import time, when firebase is *not* initialized.

Solution: place the access to `firebase.auth()` only inside functions (or the vue component object) and not during code which runs during the `import`.

Comment: You should place your onAuthStateChanged on the mounted hook, or if you plan to run it after certain action you can do it in a method